# CSS/JS animation not working after linking stylesheets

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I don't know why but even after I link my CSS/JS files to my HTML I can not see the animation. This is the code ( I can only see h1 ):

```js
var stats,
  particles = [];

Math.range = function(min, max) {
  if (!max) {
    max = min;
    min = 0;
  }
  return min + Math.random() * (max - min);
};

Math.chance = function(probability) {
  if (!probability) {
    probability = 0.5;
  }
  return Math.random() < probability;
};

function toRGB(hex) {
  var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
  return result ? {
    r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
    g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
    b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
  } : null;
}

function Particle() {
  this.isActive = (Math.chance(0.5));
}

Particle.COLORS = ['#ff0000', '#daede6', '#a3d9cc', '#738076', '#734357', '#f5496b', '#e3b1be'];

Particle.prototype.init = function() {
  this.radius = 1;
  this.color = toRGB(Particle.COLORS[Math.round(Math.random() * (Particle.COLORS.length - 1))]);
  this.alpha = 1;
  this.fade = Math.range(0.005, 0.25);
  this.grow = (this.fade > 0.01) ? Math.range(0.25, 0.5) : Math.range(0.05, 0.4);

  if (!this.isActive) {
    this.x += Math.range(-10, 10);
    this.y += Math.range(-10, 10);
  }
};

Particle.prototype.update = function() {
  if (this.isActive) {
    this.alpha -= this.fade;
    this.radius += this.grow;
  }
  if (this.alpha <= 0) {
    this.init();
  }
};

Particle.prototype.draw = function(ctx) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + this.color.r + ', ' + this.color.g + ', ' + this.color.b + ', ' + this.alpha + ')';
  ctx.fill();
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ebe9e1;
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, #FFFFFF), color-stop(100%, #ebe9e1));
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #FFFFFF 0%, #ebe9e1 100%);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #FFFFFF 0%, #ebe9e1 100%);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #FFFFFF 0%, #ebe9e1 100%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #FFFFFF 0%, #ebe9e1 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #FFFFFF 0%, #ebe9e1 100%);
}

#stats {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5%;
  font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script|Major+Mono+Display|Montserrat|Permanent+Marker" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="site.js"></script>
</head>
```

I only included the head tag because the rest is not so important in order to solve my problem. What can I do in order to display the animation? If I open the index.html page I can not see the animation I intended to see.

Comment: please provide the complete code in jsfiddle so that we can help.

Comment: Please provide the rest of the code. For now, we can't clearly see how this animation is supposed to work.

Comment: @VishwasNavadaK here it works, but when I try to open the index.html I can't see the animation. All the files are in the same folder:
https://codepen.io/nikrowell/pen/YXQoQE

Comment: And here is the fiddle using the html code:
https://jsfiddle.net/fe4n1Lam/

Comment: you have missed the sketch.min.js file, click on the js icon in the code pen you can see the external resources which are used. so download the js file from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sketch.js/1.0.0/sketch.min.js and use it

Comment: @CoderDisorder Did you check the browser console for any errors? it seems like a missing file issue.

Comment: @VishwasNavadaK I am getting this: "site.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the code for the sketch or include the script for sketch.js
I got it working after including the sketch JS

Comment: Hello man!
Even tho' the fiddle works, when I use files it doesn't. What can cause this?

Comment: Make your you are including your scripts after including the sketch js script

Comment: Here is the complete script in one file https://jsfiddle.net/4hazv3nf/1/

Comment: Thank you! Your last solution ( all script in one file ) finally worked. It also won't affect any performance because this is some kind of gift for a friend so...no one will check the code. Thank you a lot!